# Still trying to stop video from rewinding in mediaelement.js

Tags: mediaelement.js

I am still having problems with the code not stopping the video from rewinding to the beginning. The code that John posted doesn't seem to be working for me.

He said:

> I believe that the default behavior of the  element is to go back to the beginning so you'd just need to override this by listening for the ended event.

```
var player = $('#myvideo').mediaelementplayer();

player.media.addEventListener('ended', function(e) {
    player.media.setCurrentTime(player.media.duration);
}, false);
```

I placed the code in the `<head>` and in the `<script type="text/javascript">` on the page with the video and it isn't working... it still rewinds to the start.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I am seeing the same issue - as far as I can see the 'ended' event is not propagated from flash when it stops playing a video. Anyone else being able to get this to work?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Stopping instead of rewinding at the end of a video in MediaElement.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4962855/stopping-instead-of-rewinding-at-the-end-of-a-video-in-mediaelement-js)

Answer (score 4):

I wrote a fix for this problem and John merged in version 2.10.2.
There is now an option "autoRewind" that you can set to false to prevent the player from going back to the beginning.
The eventlistener is not added and there is no more need to remove it.

```
$('video').mediaelementplayer({
    autoRewind: false
});
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me, you need to call the methods on the DOM object not the jQuery object.

```
var player = $('video');
player[0].addEventListener('ended', function(e) {
                player[0].setCurrentTime(player[0].duration);
            }, false);
```

Comment: Some explanation would make the answer more useful.

Comment: The "player[0]" is just returning the DOM object.

MediaElement won't work with a jquery object. The equivilent would be:
`player.get(0).addEventListener(...);`

@GajananH

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Please edit the answer and add the explanation in the answer itself.

Answer (score 0):

should be

```
player[0].player.media
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution is to edit 'mediaelement-and-player.min.js' (if you are using that)... do a text search for c.media.setCurrentTime(0) and comment it out or delete it.